# Harvest data from Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nativescript

I am wondering if it is possible in Nativescript(in maybe any way) to pull data from google spreadsheet. I need it in the app I'm making now.

I was trying to implement https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet in my ionic app with no success, and I want to try Nativescript for it's "native" nature. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/) to access spreadsheets from any programming language. Alternatively you could also create a [web app with Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). Such a web app runs on Google's servers. It can have full access to your spreadsheets and your mobile app can communicate with it through http. That means the web app wouldn't have a UI of it's own. It just serves as a middleman to relay information.

Comment: ohhh... so that means I can create the app and not entirely rely on other third party module/plugin to communicate with google spreadsheets??? :)

Comment: You could use third party libraries and Google btw. offers libraries for several languages. But you don't need them. You can also do everything through simple http requests.